# Remover objeto do array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array, objetos, filtro

Tenho o seguinte array chamado `listDeTipoAtendimento`

```js
0: {tipoAtendimento: "ESTUDANTE", tipoServico: "ESTUDANTE", atendente: "José da Silva"}
1: {tipoAtendimento: "Gestante", tipoServico: "teste Bilhetagem", atendente: "Juliana de Olivieira"}
2: {tipoAtendimento: "Idoso", tipoServico: "Recadastramento", atendente: "Supervisor de Posto 65"}
3: {tipoAtendimento: "Idoso", tipoServico: "Recadastramento", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA"}
4: {tipoAtendimento: "Idoso", tipoServico: "Emissão da Segunda Via", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA"}
5: {tipoAtendimento: "Idoso", tipoServico: "Recadastramento", atendente: "Atendente Posto  17012019"}
6: {tipoAtendimento: "Comum", tipoServico: "Comum 11012019", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA"}
7: {tipoAtendimento: "012", tipoServico: "teste de serviço ", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA"}
8: {tipoAtendimento: "ESTUDANTE", tipoServico: "ESTUDANTE", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA"}
9: {tipoAtendimento: "Idoso", tipoServico: "Recadastramento", atendente: "Atendente Posto 16082018"}
```

E trato ele da seguinte forma:

```js
$scope.listDeTipoAtendimentoObject = $scope.listDeTipoAtendimento.map(x => { return { deTipoAtendimento: x.tipoAtendimento, atendente: x.atendente } });

$scope.listDeTipoAtendimentoObject.forEach(item => {
   item.deServico = $scope.listDeTipoAtendimento
     .filter(x => x.tipoAtendimento == item.deTipoAtendimento && x.atendente == item.atendente)
     .map(x => x.tipoServico);
   item.deServico = $scope.removeDuplicates(item.deServico);
});

//função que remove as duplicatas

$scope.removeDuplicates = function (arr) {
 let s = new Set(arr);
 let it = s.values();
 return Array.from(it);
}
```

e o `array` agora fica dessa forma:

```js
0: {deTipoAtendimento: "ESTUDANTE", atendente: "José da Silva", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2883"}
1: {deTipoAtendimento: "Gestante", atendente: "Juliana de Olivieira", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2884"}
2: {deTipoAtendimento: "Idoso", atendente: "Supervisor de Posto 65", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2885"}
3: {deTipoAtendimento: "Idoso", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA", deServico: Array(2), $$hashKey: "object:2886"}
4: {deTipoAtendimento: "Idoso", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA", deServico: Array(2), $$hashKey: "object:2887"}
5: {deTipoAtendimento: "Idoso", atendente: "Atendente Posto  17012019", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2888"}
6: {deTipoAtendimento: "Comum", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2889"}
7: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2890"}
8: {deTipoAtendimento: "ESTUDANTE", atendente: "Atendente Posto  Teste MBA", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2891"}
9: {deTipoAtendimento: "Idoso", atendente: "Atendente Posto 16082018", deServico: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2892"}
```

O meu problema é que o segundo array, mantém tanto o elemento de `index 3` quanto o de `index 4` porém eu preciso que quando eu faça essa junção do `deServico` um desses objetos seja removido, porém não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, tu queres eventualmente remover item dentro do laço que processa os itens, certo? Isso pode "quebrar o laço"...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado na real o segundo array já está com os itens processados, no exemplo o atendente tem no campo deServico um outro array com dois objetos, pois ele ja fez a junção quando uso `filter` e `map` então já estão tratados, tenho uma função que remove duplicatas `removeDuplicates` porém não esta funcionando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei a resposta dentro do stackoverflow [Remove duplicates in an object array Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032179/remove-duplicates-in-an-object-array-javascript)

Ajustei pouca coisa para o meu proposito, segue a linha de código que funcionou pra mim

```js
$scope.listDeTipoAtendimentoObject.forEach(item => {
  item.deServico = $scope.listDeTipoAtendimento
  .filter(x => x.tipoAtendimento == item.deTipoAtendimento && x.atendente == item.atendente)
  .map(x => x.tipoServico);
});

// Remove os itens repitidos
var uniq = new Set($scope.listDeTipoAtendimentoObject.map(e => JSON.stringify(e)));
var res = Array.from(uniq).map(e => JSON.parse(e));

$scope.listDeTipoAtendimentoObject = res
```